# Uncaught TypeError: Modal.dispose is not a function Bootstrap 5 Symfony 5.3

Tags: javascript, symfony5, bootstrap-5

I am making a modal on Symfony 5 with Bootstrap 5. I would like the form fields to clean up when I close the modal. Here are my files. When I close the modal I get the following error : Uncaught TypeError: myModal.dispose is not a function. Thanks for your help

app.js

```
import './styles/app.scss';

// start the Stimulus application
import './bootstrap';

import { Tooltip, Toast, Popover, Modal} from 'bootstrap';
import clearModalFields from './js/clearModalFields.js'
```

clearModalFields.js

```
var myModal = document.getElementById('createButtonForm');

myModal.addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    myModal.dispose()
})
```

createButtonForm.html.twig

```
<body>
{{ form_start(formButton) }}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#createButtonForm">Créer un bouton</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="createButtonForm" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="createButtonFormLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="createButtonFormLabel">Créer un bouton</h5>
            <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Fermer"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Label :</label>
                    {{ form_widget(formButton.label, {'attr': {'class': "form-control", 'autofocus': true}}) }}
                    {{ form_errors(formButton.label)}}
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Lien :</label>
                    {{ form_widget(formButton.link, {'attr': {'class': "form-control"}}) }}
                </div>

                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label class="col-form-label">Type de bouton :</label>
                    {{ form_widget(formButton.permissionType, {'attr': {'class': "form-control"}}) }}
                </div>
            </form>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Annuler</button>
            {{ form_widget(formButton.submit, {'attr': {'class': "btn btn-primary"}}) }}
            {{ form_widget(formButton._token) }}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br><br>
  {{ form_end(formButton) }}
</body>
```

Comment: you need to ceate your modal like this `const myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('myModal'), options)`. you are missing a major part of it

Answer (score 2):

The [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) function returns an `Element` object and that, indeed, doesn't define a `dispose` function. What you need is a `Modal` object, and you can get it by calling [`getInstance()`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#getinstance).

```
import { Modal } from 'bootstrap';

var myModal = document.getElementById('createButtonForm');

myModal.addEventListener('hide.bs.modal', function () {
    Modal.getInstance(myModal).dispose()
})
```

Comment: Ok I understand, thank you. I applied the changes but now I get an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null. when closing the modal (it can't close anymore). The error is coming from Modal._isAnimated : 

```_isAnimated() {
    return this._element.classList.contains(CLASS_NAME_FADE$4);
  }```
Which is called when I close the modal. Do you have any idea why it does that ?

Comment: @Clément.R That looks like [bootstrap animation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/list-group/#fade-effect), but no clue as to where it's called. I havent tried it but changing `hide.bs.modal` to `hidden.bs.modal` might solve the issue, as that will wait until the animation is completed to destroy the modal.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. Thanks for your help !

Comment: And you were write for the hidden.bs.modal on my animation issue thx

Comment: Modal.getInstance(myModal) (wich is from the bootstrap doc I think) returns a null element so the dispose function can't work. I managed to create a Modal instance of my modal with that : 
` var modal = new Modal(document.getElementById('createButtonForm'), {});` 
But now I still have a problem, modal.dispose() returns undefined...

Comment: `dispose()` will always return `undefined`, as it has no [`return` value](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/b613c8dbb6c30e62adaefc669130549fd9c2e28b/js/src/modal.js#L181) and if you had a reference to the modal, it will no longer work, as all references have been destroyed. About your other problem... Is the modal initialized? If not, it makes sense it returns `null` for the same reason `getElementById` failed: it isn't a modal (yet).

Comment: Ok for dispose return my bad, for my modal I get this object with console log : 
{
    "_element": null,
    "_config": null,
    "_dialog": null,
    "_backdrop": null,
    "_isShown": null,
    "_ignoreBackdropClick": null,
    "_isTransitioning": null
}

Comment: @Clément.R yeah, that object is already destroyed, otherwise `_element` wouldn't be `null`. If you dump it before calling `dispose`, you'd see that it points to an actual `Element`.

Comment: Ok thank you ! (sorry in deed I just begin learning js and bootstrap 5)

Comment: I think this should be added to Boostrap official doc's

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#modalId').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('form').trigger('reset');
})
```

Try this, which helped for me.